# how to put single double quotes together?

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following php code.

```
$msg .='<a href="#dialog" name="modal" class="icons reply_icon" onclick="reply('.$messages_row["sender_id"].','.$messages_row['sender_email'].')"><span>reply</span></a>';
```

When I click this anchor tag, I get the following error in console.

```
SyntaxError: illegal character @ in myemail@company.com
```

I know the problem is due to single double quotes but don't know how to put the correct quotes.Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Can you please attach a result of the output of your `$msg` variable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use backslash to use quotes as part of string 
And in javascript, when passing str data to function it need to be in quotes.

```
 $msg .='<a href="#dialog" name="modal" class="icons reply_icon" onclick="reply(\''.$messages_row["sender_id"].'\',\''.$messages_row['sender_email'].'\')"><span>reply</span></a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape them with: `&quot;`